# Как сделать click на элемент массива?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

у меня есть 2 массива, 1 заполнен (filterList), 2 (addList) пустой массив, при клике на элемент массива в заполненном он добавляется в пустой, как мне повесить click для popup, на определенный элемент массива (li со span например DATE) в пустом массиве в который уже добавился этот элемент на testClick(). Пытался разными способами для поиска элемента в массиве и include (все время возвращает false) и find и indexOf ничего не работает. Заранее спасибо.

```js
addFiltres(item){
      if (this.addList.indexOf(this.filterList) == this.addList.lastIndexOf(this.filterList)) {
        this.addList.push(item)
      }
      this.addList = [...new Set(this.addList)]
      },
    testClick() {
        
      },

  filterList: [
      {title: 'DATE', value: 'date'},
            {title: 'TIME', value: 'time'},
            {title: 'COLOR', value: 'color'},

        ],
        addList:[]
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
<li class="text-white text-xs uppercase font-normal not-italic px-2 py-1.75 mr-3 border border-gray-900 border-solid rounded-xs transition duration-500 hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-purple hover:bg-black-700" 
  v-for="(item, index) of addList" 
  :item="item" 
  :key="index"
  @click="testClick()"
  >
<span class="flex items-center">{{item.title}} <IconCheckMark class="stroke-white ml-2.25"/></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="border border-purple rounded-md p-2.5 inline-block min-w-35.25 bg-black-900 absolute z-110 max-h-64 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden">
<li 
   v-for="(item, index) of filterList" 
   :item="item" 
   :key="index"
class="text-xs text-white uppercase py-1.5 px-2.5 hover:bg-black-700 hover:rounded-xs hover:cursor-pointer transition-all ease-in" @click="addFiltres(item)"
          >
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: очень странно видеть `indexOf(this.filterList)` , почему не `indexOf(item)` ?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, добрый день, при чем здесь это если, вопрос про клик на элемент из массива ?

Comment: Запустил этот пример, при клике на элемент из addList, testClick отрабатывает, не могу понять,  какое должно быть поведение?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, я повесил тестовый клик, мне надо чтобы клик отрабатывался по элементe из массива addList со значением DATE, после клика снизу открывается popup.

Comment: В testClick  можно передавать `item`, внутри сделать `if (item.title === 'DATE') {...} ` и внутри этого условия открывать popup. Похоже проблема не с кликом, а с открытием popup.